# Property Declaration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, declaration

OrderDetailsView.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @protocol OrderDetailsViewDelegate;

    @interface OrderDetailsView : UIViewController {
        IBOutlet UITextView *OrderDetails;
        NSString *selectedOrder;

        id <OrderDetailsViewDelegate> delegate;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <OrderDetailsViewDelegate> delegate;
    - (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
    @end

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* selectedOrder;
    @end


    @protocol OrderDetailsViewDelegate
    - (void)OrderDetailsViewDidFinish:(OrderDetailsView *)controller;
    @end
```

OrderDetailsView.m

```
#import "OrderDetailsView.h"


@implementation OrderDetailsView

@synthesize selectedOrder;
@synthesize delegate;
```

i am getting the error

property declaration not in @interface or @implementation context

Comment: I think you might be confused about what the @end keyword is the end of. You use @end to end an @interface, @protocol or @implementation. So in your example you have the @interface there, you declare the variables in {} and then all the properties and methods, and then you @end the @interface. The same thing with the @protocol and the @implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@end
```

Must present only once in interface declaration, so remove redundant one (after done method)

Comment: also, I do believe an @end is needed for the @implementation.

Comment: the last @end corresponds to the property declaration so it is ok

Comment: do you mean the protocol declaration?

Comment: sorry, protocol of course. end of the working day - starting to confuse everything :)